# How to do a count the number of previous occurence in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe.

| cust_id | apply_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-06-2014 |
| 1 | 01-07-2014 |
| 1 | 01-04-2018 |
| 1 | 01-07-2018 |
| 2 | 01-04-2015 |
| 2 | 01-05-2015 |
| 2 | 01-06-2015 |
| 2 | 01-09-2015 |

I want to calculate the number of applications the customer made in the previous 6 months
excluding the current application.

So the output sholud be:

| cust_id | apply_date | apps_prev_180_days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-06-2014 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-07-2014 | 1 |
| 1 | 01-04-2018 | 0 |
| 1 | 01-07-2018 | 1 |
| 2 | 01-04-2015 | 0 |
| 2 | 01-05-2015 | 1 |
| 2 | 01-06-2015 | 2 |
| 2 | 01-09-2015 | 3 |

I have tried to create lag variable within a window function and count the apps, however that only considers the previous application and not all applications.
Any pointers how to do this ?

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code - preferably a [mcve] - as well its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a `Window` function and the method `.rangeBetween` (in seconds) to define custom time intervals

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# convert string type to actual date (if not done yet)
df = df.withColumn('apply_date', F.to_date('apply_date', 'dd-MM-yyyy'))

# number of days and seconds for time interval
days = 180
unix_seconds = days * 86400

# define window
w = Window\
  .partitionBy('cust_id')\
  .orderBy(F.col('apply_date').cast('timestamp').cast('long'))\
  .rangeBetween(-unix_seconds, -1)

df = df.withColumn('apps_prev_180_days', F.count('cust_id').over(w))

df.show()

+-------+----------+------------------+
|cust_id|apply_date|apps_prev_180_days|
+-------+----------+------------------+
|      1|2014-06-01|                 0|
|      1|2014-07-01|                 1|
|      1|2018-04-01|                 0|
|      1|2018-07-01|                 1|
|      2|2015-04-01|                 0|
|      2|2015-05-01|                 1|
|      2|2015-06-01|                 2|
|      2|2015-09-01|                 3|
+-------+----------+------------------+
```

In this case, `.rangeBetween(-unix_seconds, -1)` defines a time interval from 180 days ago to the previos second (`-1`); this allows us to exclude the current application from the count.

Comment: Thank you @RicS for the answer. Works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df.withColumn(
    "apps_prev_180_days",
    F.count("*").over(
        W.partitionBy("cust_id")
        .orderBy(F.unix_timestamp("apply_date"))  # Date as unix timestamp (seconds)
        .rangeBetween(-(180 * 24 * 3600), -1)  # 180 days in secondes
    ),
).show()

+-------+----------+------------------+
|cust_id|apply_date|apps_prev_180_days|
+-------+----------+------------------+
|      1|2014-06-01|                 0|
|      1|2014-07-01|                 1|
|      1|2018-04-01|                 0|
|      1|2018-07-01|                 1|
|      2|2015-04-01|                 0|
|      2|2015-05-01|                 1|
|      2|2015-06-01|                 2|
|      2|2015-09-01|                 3|
+-------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi Steven, no doubt you have done it on your own, but I'm afraid it seems very similar (if not almost equal) to my previous answer

Comment: @RicS Sorry... i was probably typing it while you also post your answer. Still, the functions used are not exactly the same, and your answer is much more complete in term of explanations

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer, hence I have accepted @RicS answer.

Comment: @akp No prob, that's fair :) and his answer is more explicit ;)